# What do different values represent for active_storage.resolve_model_to_route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reverse-proxy, cdn, rails-activestorage

So there are two values for `resolve_model_to_route`:

```
Rails.application.config.active_storage.resolve_model_to_route = 
  :rails_storage_proxy || :rails_storage_redirect
```

They both generate two different URLs:

1. With `:rails_storage_proxy`, the URL goes like this: `rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy`
2. With `:rails_storage_redirect`, the URL goes like this: `rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect`

What's the difference between these two URLs?

What I have found on my own: the URL: `rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy` will return a storage file from a CDN, instead of serving a file directly from a storage service like S3, and if so, where do we mention CDN URL here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`resolve_model_to_route`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-track-variants) is a configuration option in Ruby on Rails' Active Storage framework, used to globally change how Active Storage files are delivered, and that can indeed take two values: `:rails_storage_proxy` and `:rails_storage_redirect`.

- The `:rails_storage_proxy` option makes Active Storage serve files through the application. This can be useful in situations where you want to apply application logic before serving a file, such as authentication or transformations.
- The `:rails_storage_redirect` option, on the other hand, causes Active Storage to generate a URL for the file in the storage service (like S3, Azure, Google Cloud, etc.) and then redirects the client to that URL. This takes the load of serving files off of your application and onto the storage service, but it means that the file is served directly to the client without any intervention from your application.

See also "[Rails now serves files via proxy](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/06/22/rails-active-storage-proxy/)" by [Swaathi Kakarla](https://twitter.com/imswaathik/)

---

Regarding the CDN: using a CDN with Active Storage generally involves configuring your storage service (like S3) to use the CDN, rather than configuring Active Storage itself.
If your storage service is set up to use a CDN, then when Active Storage generates a URL for a file (using either `:rails_storage_proxy` or `:rails_storage_redirect`), that URL will be a CDN URL. The specific process for setting this up would depend on the storage service and CDN you are using.

The proxy feature introduced in Rails 6.1 made this process easier and more flexible. The proxy feature provides a permanent URL to an asset through your Rails application instead of an expiring URL, which enables a CDN to cache the file after the first request.
See "[The Complete Guide to using a CDN with Rails Active Storage](https://www.simplefileupload.com/blog/active-storage-cdn)" by [Colleen Schnettler](https://twitter.com/leenyburger)

To configure your Rails application to use a CDN with Active Storage, you need to make the following changes:

- In your `storage.yml` file, add the `public:true` setting to your configuration.
- In your routes, modify the way files are served to provide a permanent URL. This can be done by modifying the `routes.rb` file to use the route directly. Then, in your views, use a helper like `cdn_image_url(@user.avatar)` to serve your files through the CDN.
- If you want to proxy all your files, you can add an initializer to your application. Create an `active_storage.rb` file in `config/initializers` with the following line: `Rails.application.config.active_storage.resolve_model_to_route = :rails_storage_proxy`. This will make all files use the proxy URL.
- You can also use route helpers directly to generate the proxy URL. For example, you could use `rails_storage_proxy_path(@user.avatar)` in your view, which also accepts parameters allowing you to specify your CDN host.

To connect your CDN to your application, you will need to:

- Select a CDN and add your custom domain to your application settings (if using a platform like Heroku).
- Add the target to your DNS provider. This is typically provided after adding a custom domain with your hosting provider.
- Complete the setup of your chosen CDN. This typically involves adding additional DNS records as prompted by your CDN provider.
- Wait for the DNS to resolve, then complete the CDN setup. Add the `CDN_HOST` as an environment variable on your production environment.

---

> I'm using S3 – it is public and in front of Amazon S3, Cloudflare has been enabled via the bucket permission policy. Now, when Rails generates a URL, and I pass the host(host is cdn.myapp.com and this domain is forwarded to Amazon S3), the URL looks like: `https://cdn.myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/....png`.
> The thing is: Rails app is hosted at `myapp.com`, and not at `cdn.myapp.com`.
> `cdn.myapp.com` is for accessing the S3 bucket via Cloudflare, so the '`host`' thing does not make sense here.
>
> What works out of box is: `["cdn.myapp.com" + object.key]`.
> But I'm here trying to make sense of how Rails can help us hide this URL, and could redirect a user to this URL automatically.

So you do construct an URL manually in your code. You concatenates the string `"cdn.myapp.com"` with the `object.key` where `object` is an instance of an Active Storage object (a file or image, for example) and `key` is a unique identifier for the file in the storage system.

This manual URL construction might be done in a view or a controller, anywhere you need to create a URL to access a stored file, as in:

```rb
<%= image_tag "https://cdn.myapp.com/#{@user.avatar.key}" %>
```

Wtih `@user.avatar` being an Active Storage object and `key` the unique identifier for the file on the storage service.
That would  construct a URL directly to the file on the CDN.

However, as you have noted, this exposes the direct URL to the file, which might not be what you want.

The proxy method provided by Active Storage allows for the creation of permanent URLs that hide the actual storage location of the files and can be used with a CDN. These permanent URLs are constructed in the format `https://myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/...`.

In your particular setup, since you are using a CDN, you would need to adjust the routing and serving of your files to make use of this feature. This can be achieved by updating your `storage.yml` and `routes.rb` files accordingly.

If you want to use Rails to generate these URLs automatically, you will need to leverage Rails' proxy feature and some routing configurations. As we discussed earlier, the proxy feature provides a permanent URL to an asset through your Rails application, which can then be served through your CDN.

So, ensure your Rails application is set to use proxying for Active Storage. If you want to proxy all your files, add the following line to an initializer in your application (e.g., create a `config/initializers/active_storage.rb` file):

```rb
Rails.application.config.active_storage.resolve_model_to_route = :rails_storage_proxy
```

With this configuration, standard Rails view calls such as `<%= image_tag (@user.avatar), width: 500, height: 500 %>` will produce a proxy URL.

In your Rails application's configuration, set the `host` option to the domain of your CDN (i.e., `cdn.myapp.com`). This can be done in your `production.rb` file (or `development.rb` for testing) using `config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://cdn.myapp.com'`.

Finally, update your `storage.yml` with the appropriate configuration for Amazon S3 and make it public:

```yaml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <your_access_key_id>
  secret_access_key: <your_secret_access_key>
  region: <your_region>
  bucket: <your_bucket_name>
  public: true
```

When you need to display an asset, use the Rails view helpers as you would normally. For example, `<%= image_tag @user.avatar %>`.
With the proxying and asset host configuration, Rails should automatically generate URLs in the form you have described, like `https://cdn.myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/....png`.

This configuration should allow Rails to generate the appropriate URLs for your assets, which are served via your Cloudflare CDN and Amazon S3 bucket. The CDN should handle caching and delivery of the assets, improving load times and reducing server load. The URLs generated by Rails will be permanent and do not reveal the direct link to the asset in the S3 bucket.

Do replace the placeholders `<...>` in the `storage.yml` with your actual AWS credentials and bucket information (and make sure to not leak said credentials!).

---

> To confirm: putting `config.asset_host = 'cdn.myapp.com'`, Rails will generate a URL like "myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/..png" and that will eventually redirect to the CDN URL?
>
> I'm asking this, because I couldn't confirm it anywhere in the app, or in the browser.

Not quite. If you set `config.asset_host` to `'cdn.myapp.com'`, Rails will generate URLs that start with `'cdn.myapp.com'` for your assets. It does not redirect to the CDN URL, instead the request for the asset will directly go to the CDN. If the asset is not already cached on the CDN, the CDN will fetch it from your application server, cache it, and serve it.

The generated URL for the asset in Rails would look something like: `'cdn.myapp.com/assets/image.png'` for regular assets and `'cdn.myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/..png'` for Active Storage assets if you are using the proxy feature.

However, keep in mind that the behavior you are expecting, where the CDN URL is visible in the browser, may not happen as you expect. When you configure a CDN, the URL the user sees in their browser might not change to reflect the CDN URL - the CDN operates as a 'transparent' layer between the user and your server. The user requests a resource from your server's URL, and the CDN intercepts this request and serves the resource if it can. If it cannot (because the resource is not in its cache), it requests the resource from your server, caches it, and then serves it to the user.

So the user may not see a different URL in their browser when a CDN is used. You can usually verify that the CDN is working by checking the network traffic in your browser's developer tools, and looking at the headers for asset requests. A header like `X-Cache: HIT` would indicate that the CDN is serving the resource.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm using S3 – it's public and in front of Amazon S3, Cloudflare has been enabled via the bucket permission policy.

Now, when Rails generates a URL, and I pass the host(host is cdn.myapp.com and this domain is forwarded to Amazon S3), the URL looks like: https://cdn.myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/....png The thing is: Rails app is hosted at myapp.com, and not at cdn.myapp.com. cdn.myapp.com is for accessing the S3 bucket via Cloudflare, so the 'host' thing doesn't make sense here.

Comment: What works out of box is: ["cdn.myapp.com" + object.key]. But I'm here trying to make sense of how Rails can help us hide this URL, and could redirect a user to this URL automatically.

Comment: Just one last thing to confirm: putting config.asset_host = 'cdn.myapp.com', Rails will generate a URL like "myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/..png" and that will eventually redirect to the CDN URL. I'm asking this, because I couldn't confirm it anywhere in the app, or in the browser.

Comment: @ArslanAli I have edited the answer (again) to address your comment.